API mgmt. error in bicep when setting backend
I am setting Azure APIM in bicep. There is a section to setup the backend that goes like this:

resource backend_test 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 'backend_test'
  parent: apimservice 
  properties: {
      url: api_url
      protocol: 'http'
      // credentials: {
      //     authorization: {
      //         parameter: 'query'
      //         scheme: 'basic'
      //     }
      // }
  }
}

In the line when I setup the protocol protocol: 'http', if I set it to https it fails with the unsupported protocol error. Protocol is not supported (Code: ValidationError, Target: protocol), if I leave it to http it works. The documentation says that this fields can support both http and https.
I am not sure how to go about this.
Thanks

Based on the Documentation only the following values are valid: 'http','soap'

If you check the Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends service backend properties, the field protocol only supports http and soap types and thanks @Markus Meyer
for suggesting the similar one. . It doesn't support https protocol in the latest releases. (Eg: 2023-05-01-preview).
param apiManagementName string = 'apiservice${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
param publisherEmail string = "abc@gmail.com"
param publisherName string = "newpublisher"
param sku string = 'Developer'
param skuCount int = 1
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource apiManagementService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: apiManagementName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sku
    capacity: skuCount
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: publisherEmail
    publisherName: publisherName
  }
}
resource backend_test 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: 'backend_test'
  parent: apiManagementService 
  properties: {
    url: 'https://xxx.contoso.com'
      protocol: 'http'
       credentials: {
          authorization: {
              parameter: 'query'
              scheme: 'basic'
          }
       }
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



That is not to say that APIM does not support as a protocol of communication with backend. It absolutely does, it's just from backend perspective protocol:http specifies HTTP(S) backend, and actual HTTP or HTTPS is specified in backend URL.
